# Smarty :Truncate no. of divs in {section}

Tags: php, http, smarty

I have the categories & subcategories. I want to select the all parent categories & subcategories. But want to show only 3-4 subcategories under each parent category.

My Php **Code**

```
 /******Start Categories********/
  $ca=mysql_query('select * from category where parent_id=0');
  while($ca1 = mysql_fetch_array($ca))
{
$ca2[]=$ca1;
}
$smarty->assign('ca2',$ca2);


  /******End Categories********/
   /******Start SubCategories********/
  $sub=mysql_query('select * from category where parent_id!=0 ');
  while($sub1 = mysql_fetch_array($sub))
{
$sub2[]=$sub1;
}
$smarty->assign('sub2',$sub2);


  /******End SubCategories********/
```

And Tpl **Code:**

```
<div id="sub_ltcol">
                {section name=loopc loop=$ca2}
                    <div id="gr_design">
                        <div id="gr_head">
                            <h4>{$ca2[loopc].category_name}</h4>
                        </div>
                        {section name=loops loop=$sub2}
                        {if $ca2[loopc].category_id eq $sub2[loops].parent_id}
                        <div id="gr_body">
                            <ul>
                            <li>
                                    <div class="arw_icon"><img src="images/arw_icon.png"></div>
                                    <a href="#">{$sub2[loops].category_name}</a>
                                </li>
                                <div class="dotted_line"></div>
                            </ul>
                        </div>{/if}
                        {/section}
                    </div>
                    {/section}


                </div>
```

I want to show the `<li>` tag only 3-4 times.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
{section name=loops loop=$sub2}
  {if $ca2[loopc].category_id eq $sub2[loops].parent_id AND $smarty.section.loops.iteration <= 4}

      ...
  {/if}

{/section}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method:

```
<div id="sub_ltcol">
{section name=loopc loop=$ca2}
    <div id="gr_design">
        <div id="gr_head">
            <h4>{$ca2[loopc].category_name}</h4>
        </div>
        {section name=loops loop=$sub2}
        {if $ca2[loopc].category_id eq $sub2[loops].parent_id}
        {if $smarty.foreach.loops.index lte 3}
        <div id="gr_body">
            <ul>
            <li>
                    <div class="arw_icon"><img src="images/arw_icon.png"></div>
                    <a href="#">{$sub2[loops].category_name}</a>
                </li>
                <div class="dotted_line"></div>
            </ul>
        </div>{/if}
        {/if}
    {/section}
</div>
{/section}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you will require to show only 3 subcategories, take only this much from DB and show it.
you can use limit attribute for same

```
 /******Start SubCategories********/
  $sub=mysql_query('select * from category where parent_id!=0 limit 3');
```

it help to improve page loading performance also.